# How to apply UNION only in certain cases (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have the following - simplified - query:

```
SELECT id
FROM table_x
UNION ALL 
SELECT 0 AS id
```

However, I only want to attach the UNION part in case the first part of the query returns at least 1 result, e.g.:

table_x with one entry (id = 1):

```
table_x: 1
Current and desired result: 1, 0
```

table_x empty:

```
table_x: empty
Current result: 0
Desired result: empty
```

Is there any way to achieve this within the query? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Within the query you cannot, the two selects are not aware of each other. You can wrap the union into a subquery and filter its results in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your table exists. you can do something like this.

```
SELECT
IF ( a is NULL, NULL, CONCAT(a,",",b))
FROM(
SELECT
  (SELECT * From myTable WHERE id = 2) a
  ,(SELECT 0) b
  ) C
```

The result is empty

The result for id = 1 
would be

```
IF ( a is NULL, NULL, CONCAT(a,",",b))
1,0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers. I solved the problem with the following approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table_x) AS counter,
        id 
    FROM table_x
    UNION ALL
    SELECT (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table_x) AS counter,
        0 AS id) a
WHERE a.counter > 0
```